# Grunt change path to all files

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

Hell 
I do not know how i can change my path using grunt tasks. I need to change my path for all files (css, js, images etc). I do not found any example how to do it ?

For example now grunt create something like that :

```
<script src="scripts/d41d8cd9.plugins.js"></script>
```

And i need something like that :

```
<script src="myapp/scripts/d41d8cd9.plugins.js"></script>
```

So i need to do it for dist , and for all path

Comment: Have you [read this](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks)?

Comment: You need to post the relevant configuration and describe what tasks you are using before we can help. Posting a snippet and an expected result isn't enough.

Comment: Here is my grun configuration file : http://pastebin.com/PsaHhYBW

Comment: @ŁukaszWoźniczka, just wondering, did you find a way for this?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Think you need to update your rev configuration then.

```
rev: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      src: [
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/myapp/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/myapp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/myapp/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/myapp/styles/fonts/*'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope - didnt work... Still giving output as <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no such grunt plugin exist, However I believe you can achieve the same by using [grunt-string-replace](https://github.com/erickrdch/grunt-string-replace) plugin,

I am planning to work on similar plugin, which would make this task trivial